# pass js variable to controller and build new view in ci

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have onclick function in view file like:

```
<span onclick="show_details('<?php echo $cmp['symbol']; ?>',<?php echo $cmp['id']; ?>);">Details</span>
```

and in js I did like:

```
 function show_details(symbol,id){
window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url();?>' + 'company';
}
```

I have to load another view through the controller company and need symbol and id in that view but I shouldn't pass the variables in window.location.

Is there any method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can Pass Using AJAX

```
$.get('<?php echo base_url();?>'+'company/'+symbol+id);
```